# Magento - order details are not displayed in the admin panel

Tags: magento

We have an ecommerce magento store. Right now, we are experiencing a weird problem, which i am unable to understand and debug.

For some of the orders, no details are displayed in the order details page of magento admin, though the mail is correctly sent to the client and cc'd to our email id.

**Screenshot for admin order details page :-**

[image]

**Screenshot for email containing order details :-**

[image]

Why is this happening ?? I tried to check the pattern but was unable to. Please help me on this issue as i am not a pro in magento and any help from your side will do the work for me.

Comment: go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings` and enable logging. Then go to order view page. Then check `var/exception.log` or `var/system.log`

Comment: It looks like adminhtml template is missing. Enabling logging will tell you which one.

Comment: Logging was already enabled. I downloaded both the files but dont know what to see there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than likely you have a local or community module causing some kinds of fault, if the page is not rendering all the way for some orders, I would presume these are orders that are using this local and/or community module.

A few things you can try are:

1) disable all local modules via `local.xml`

2) disable community modules via `app/etc/Company_Modulename.xml` and set `active` to `false`

after disabling each retry viewing the orders until you find the culprit.

Also, viewing the page source may help lead to where the output is stopping and there also may be errors at the very end of the page source.

hope this helps.

Comment: in the source view i can see the values, i just saw that...Dont know why they aren't displayed on the page.

Comment: the left link list is getting broken. I mean some of the code is not rendered. The left link list is incomplete and doesn't show up. Just one list item is opened and never closed. After that the corresponding items are not there.

Comment: `<li >
        <a href="#" id="sales_order_view_tabs_order_info" name="order_info" title="Order Information" class="tab-item-link ">
            <span><span class="changed" title="The information in this tab has been changed."></span><span class="error" title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving."></span>Information</span>
        </a>`

Comment: the list item is not closed and the following list items dont come up in the source-view. Why the list is broken and not rendered.

Comment: Have you tried disabling community and/or local modules to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay So, How did you solved it - Which module/extension did you disabled or what code/db changes have you done? - Facing same

Answer (score 8):

Try also this, it worked for me (from https://magentary.com/kb/php-syntax-error-after-supee-7405-unexpected/):

> **Problem description**
>
> After SUPEE-7405 patch Sales Order Management screen in Magento Backend is blank or the following error is reported in PHP error log:
>
> > PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php on line 124
>
> **Cause**
>
> SUPEE-7405 is prepared with PHP 5.4 in mind, older PHP versions are incompatible with new language constructions used.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Change line 124 in *app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php* from `$links = [];` to `$links = array();`:
>
> ```
> --- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
> +++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
>
> @@ -121,7 +121,7 @@
>      public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
>      {
>          if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
> -            $links = [];
> +            $links = array();
>              $i = 1;
>              $data = str_replace('%', '%%', $data);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem when I replace the `tax.phtml` file in

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals`

with my original file. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled all plugins. It seemed that the apptha one step checkout plugin was responsible for this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this issue is due to default Magento, as the files does not point to any third party checkout extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If the SUPEE-7405 patch has caused this, please check that your system does not run on PHP 5.3.

The patch breaks PHP 5.3 compatibility, by introducing usage of array literals in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php (line 124), which became available in PHP since version 5.4, so the minimum PHP version required, after applying it, is PHP 5.4:

```
// patched app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php lines 121-124
public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
        $links = [];
```

To fix this, and restore PHP 5.3 compatibility (allowing orders to show up again in admin screens), simply correct this with old PHP5.3 equivalent:

```
// patched and fixed app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php lines 121-124
public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
        $links = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change PHP 5.3 to 5.6 on your Server , logout and in . Resfresh you Cache.
It will be run.
For the Version 1.9.2.3 magento.