# Magento admin order view page collapsed to the left column?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My magento admin order view ( order detail ) page has been collapsed to the left section of page.

Please help if anyone know about this issue,

Thanks,

Comment: question is not clear..

Comment: are you facing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556164/magento-order-details-are-not-displayed-in-the-admin-panel

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21549814/315024