# Individual order details not displaying in admin CE 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9

Orders show on Dashboard page and seem to be saved in DB fine when I use phpmyadmin to check. However detail is not displayed when an order is clicked on, as per image.
[screenshot of order detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf2CP.jpg)
I have tried disabling local modules via app/etc/local.xml, but no change when retesting.
Logs are enabled. In var/log only exception.log exists and it does not get added to when trying to view the affected page. Below are the contents of that log:

```
2016-01-25T00:11:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Please enter a valid email address.
Trace: #0 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php(48): Mage::throwException('Please enter a ...')
#1 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController->newAction()
#2 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#3 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/avai007/public_html/onlineshop/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

There are a couple of other questions similar to mine but either not identical problem or too old now for me to find the files they are talking about, in my installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via a recent answer to an older question of another user.

Essentially there was a line in a helper file that was not compatible with the PHP version running on server. A quick modification to one line and its fine again:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009810/5835914